# Are there any symbols that come after all letters in Unix's alphabetical sorting?

Tags: unix, filenames, ls

When I organize my directories I often want certain directories to stand out in `ls`. For example, I will sometimes have a directory called `#backup#` and this will end up in the top of the list of directories, rather than in between all directories starting in "b". Sometimes, though, I want a directory to be at the bottom of the list, but I haven't found any symbol that achieves this. (The closest I've come is `z#name#z`, but this doesn't quite cut it.) So: Are there any symbols that come after all letters in Unix's alphabetical sorting?

Comment: Are the sets listed in sort order there?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any (e.g. [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) or [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) [it depends upon your encoding and localization]) character except NULL (used as the ending of filepath) and `/` (used to separate directories in file path). See [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html). You might consider using `~` because several utilities (see [indent(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/indent.1.html), [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html)....) adopt the *convention* to backup file `/home/nag/foo` as `/home/nag/foo~`. AFAIK `#foo#`  could be used by `emacs` to backup temporarily an edited (but unsaved) file `foo`.